# How do I temporarily plug a broken outdoor spigot?

Tags: faucet

A spigot outside of my home just broke halfway off. There's no longer a way to screw a hose on or anything that can stop the flow of water, and I don't know of any plumbing companies near me that can operate at this time. So I turned off the water supply in order to stop the waste of water. Is there a way that I can plug the spigot so I can use the water in the rest of my house? Or do I have to wait until I can secure a plumber?

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you can use a wrench or not, or if your house was plumbed sensibly...

If your house was plumbed sensibly, there will be an additional valve somewhere in the house, generally near the hose spigot, that will shut off only the water to the spigot, not the whole house.

If not you need to unscrew the broken spigot, and (depending on what sort of threads it has) put on a cap or put in a plug. Or just put on a new spigot.

Comment: Is it likely that this valve will be under the house? I'm not sure how to navigate underneath it, and it's a very narrow crawlspace. (I'm fine with getting a cap or plug and replacing the spigot, though.)

Comment: You would want to follow the pipe from the broken part back, looking to see if there is another valve *(and in your case, it most likely would be under the house) depending on how much pipe is exposed. It may go up into a utility room/closet, if so, try the valves in there that appear to follow the same track as the broken spigot pipe.If the pipe T's off somewhere, try following it back more towards a likely source. You could tape off the broken spigot and open a sink valve, for temporary use, at least to fill and flush etc without making as much of a mess as you would otherwise.

Comment: I have not seen a valve for a spigot on a newer hose once in 10 years.  The only valves I have seen is for spigots that are not frostfree and need winterized on older homes.  This would be a nice feature though!